# Unsigned integers overflow does not "wrap around"

Tags: c, printf, integer-overflow

I read following line from [Integer Overflow Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

> while unsigned integer overflow causes the number to be reduced modulo
>   a power of two, meaning that unsigned integers "wrap around" on
>   overflow.

I have below code where I am trying to create a hash function and got int overflow situation. I tried to mitigate it by using `unsigned int` but it didn't work and I was able to see negative values.

I know I can handle it other way and it works, as shown in my code comment -  `Comment 2:`. But is it right way and why `unsigned int` was not wrapping around and overflowing?

```
int hash(char *word) {
    char *temp = word;
    unsigned int hash = 0; // Comment 1: I tried to handle int overflow using "unsigned" int.
    while (*word != '\0') {
        // Comment 2: This works but I do not want to go this way. 
        //while ((hash * PRIME_MULTIPLIER) < 0) {
        //    hash = (hash * PRIME_MULTIPLIER) + 2147483647;
        //}
        hash = hash * PRIME_MULTIPLIER + *word;
        word++;
    }
    printf("Hash for %s is %d\n", temp, hash);
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what do you really mean?

Comment: Note that this is a very suboptimal choice for the prime number.  You are basically computing `word[0] - word[1] + word[2] - word[3]...`

Comment: @ChrisBeck Updated. I meant I was able to see negative values.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I didn't got what you mean?

Comment: @hagrawal: Why is your return type `int` if you want an unsigned result?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I thought your `PRIME_MULTIPLIER` was 2147483647.

Comment: Dude, you're going to "see negative numbers" ... if you use a *SIGNED* format specifier like `printf ("%d", i)`!  Substitute `'%u"!`  Here is a good link on "printf" and format specifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/.  ALSO: change your "hash()" return value to UNSIGNED: `unsigned hash(char * word)`

Comment: @Blastfurnace That's not the concern. dbush has nailed it with his answer.

Comment: @hagrawal: Your function will return negative values. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Easy. That's what not my question was for. My code may have 100 other things because it could be my testing code. My concern was overflow values when I was printing and dbush nailed the same.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks mate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier for `printf`.  For an `unsigned int`,  you should be using `%u` instead of `%d`.

Also, you should be returning an `unsigned int` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much buddy. Format specifier was the culprit. I was not worried about return type though.

Comment: Buddy, one small doubt - at the end of my while loop, `hash` will have a positive value because it is `unsigned int`, so even though when I was using %d format specifier, how come negative value was getting printed. Ideally, unsigned int means there is no bit to hold sign value, then how come negative value was getting printed?

Comment: @hagrawal It was interpreting the unsigned value as a signed value.  For example if `hash` contains `0xFFFFFFFF`, using `%d` will output `-1` while `%u` will output `4294967295`.

Comment: Please correct me on my understanding - this means when MSB of my unsigned int would be 1 then %d would consider it as negative value?